# `npm i` still ask for Angular 13 despite having updated my projects to Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, dependencies

### The problem

I have 2 Angular projects. The first is a library that is used in the second project. I upgraded both projects using [this guide](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=13.0-14.0) from Angular 13 to Angular 14.

The problem is that when I do an `npm i` on project 2, it tells me that the library still needs Angular 3 and I can't figure out why.

This is the error message when doing `npm i` in the project 2:

```
While resolving: component-cookies@1.10.0
Found: @angular/common@14.3.0
node_modules/@angular/common
  @angular/common@"^14.3.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/common@"~13.1.2" from @xxx/library@1.148.0-rc.34369
node_modules/@xxx/library
  @xxx/library@"1.148.0-rc.34369" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

This is the `package.json` of the library:

```json
{
  "name": "xxx-library",
  "version": "1.148.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run build:library && ng serve",
    ... more scripts
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.6.6",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.6.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "convert-excel-to-json": "^1.7.0",
    "cy2": "^2.0.0",
    "cypress": "^8.7.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.19.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "inquirer": "^8.1.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "ng-packagr": "^14.2.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^15.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "simple-git": "^3.19.1",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^34.0.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^6.0.3",
    "stylelint-scss": "^5.0.1",
    "stylelint": "^15.10.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "cucumberJson": {
      "generate": true,
      "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber-json",
      "filePrefix": "",
      "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
    }
  },
  "exports": {
    "./icons": "./projects/xxx-library/src/assets/scss/core/_icons.scss"
  }
}
```

This is the `package.json` of the project 2:

```json
{
  "name": "component-cookies",
  "version": "1.10.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:library": "ng build component",
    "build:web-component": "ng build web-component",
    "build:projects": "ng build component && ng build web-component",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .ts --fix",
    "stylelint": "stylelint **/*.scss --max-warnings 0",
    "stylelint:fix": "stylelint **/*.scss --fix",
    "ci:test:e2e": "echo 'no tests available for this project'",
    "ci:build:build": "ng build component --configuration production && ng build web-component --configuration production",
    "ci:build:lint": "mkdir -p ./lint-reports/ && eslint . --ext .ts -f json > ./lint-reports/eslint-results.json && stylelint **/*.scss --max-warnings 0 -f json --output-file ./lint-reports/stylelint-results.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
    "@xxx/library": "1.148.0-rc.34370",
    "document-register-element": "^1.7.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.19.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-packagr": "14.2.0",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^14.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^15.0.1",
    "stylelint": "^15.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^34.0.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^6.0.3",
    "stylelint-scss": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  }
}
```

### Solutions i tried

Things i tried to solve this problem:

1. Delete the `package-lock.json` on both projects and run again `npm i`.
2. Delete the `package-lock.json` + `node-modules`+ `.angular/cache` and run again `npm i`.
3. Delete both local project and reinstall everything from scratch from the remote branch.
4. Updating local Node version from 16 to 18.
5. Searching in the library `package-lock.json` a dependency that use Angular 13.

#### Note:

After searching in the library `package-lock.json` the only dependency that had a reference to angular/common 13 was:

```json
...
   "node_modules/@ngx-translate/http-loader": {
      "version": "7.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@ngx-translate/http-loader/-/http-loader-7.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-j+NpXXlcGVdyUNyY/qsJrqqeAdJdizCd+GKh3usXExSqy1aE9866jlAIL+xrfDU4w+LiMoma5pgE4emvFebZmA==",
      "dependencies": {
        "tslib": "^2.3.0"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": ">=13.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": ">=14.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0"
      }
    },
...
```

But after having read [that post](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/1378) , I understand that everything is correct and that it should work. However it is the only reference to Angular 13 that appears in the `package-lock`. So I can't find why, when I install the library in project 2, it keeps asking me for Angular 13.

### Updates

Doing `npm ls @angular/common` returns:

```
xxx-library@1.148.0 C:\Users\username\workspace\xxx\library
├── @angular/common@14.3.0
├─┬ @angular/forms@14.3.0
│ └── @angular/common@14.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@14.3.0
│ └── @angular/common@14.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @angular/platform-browser@14.3.0
│ └── @angular/common@14.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @angular/router@14.3.0
│ └── @angular/common@14.3.0 deduped
└─┬ @ngx-translate/http-loader@7.0.0
  └── @angular/common@14.3.0 deduped
```

Comment: Can you check what `npm ls @angular/common` returns ?

Comment: i just added an update with the result

Answer (score 0):

After searching, i discovered that the projects have nested projects. So inside the project there is more than one package.json.
And the ng update angular command only update the first one.
Had to change manually Angular version in all of them.